# How to replace character in Powershell with initial character + a space

Tags: powershell

Hopefully this question isn't already answered on the site. I want to replace every number in a string with that number and a space. So here's what I have right now:

```
"31222829" -replace ("[0-9]","$0 ")
```

The [0-9] looks for any numbers, and replaces it with that character and the space. However, it doesn't work. I saw from another website to use $0 but I'm not sure what it means.The output I was looking for was

```
3 1 2 2 2 8 2 9
```

But it just gives me a blank line. Any suggestions?

LardPies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably isn't the right way to do it, but it works.

```
("31222829").GetEnumerator() -join " "
```

The `.GetEnumerator` method iterates over each character in the string
The `-join` operator will then join all of those characters with the `" "` space

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

```
PS> "31222829" -replace '[0-9]', '$& '
3 1 2 2 2 8 2 9
```

Note that the output string has a trailing space, given that each digit in the input (`[0-9]`) is replaced by itself (`$&`) followed by a space.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `"31222829" -replace ("[0-9]","$0 ")`

- While enclosing the two RHS operands in `(...)` doesn't impede functionality, it's not really helpful to conceive of them as an *array* - just enumerate them with `,`, don't enclose them in `(...)`.
- Generally, **use `'...'` rather than `"..."` for the RHS operands** (the regex to match and the replacement operand), so as to prevent confusion between PowerShell's string expansion (interpolation) and what the `-replace` operator ultimately sees.

  - Case in point: Due to use of `"..."` in the replacement operand, PowerShell's string interpolation would actually expand `$0` as a *variable* up front, which in the absence of a variable expands to the *empty string* - that is why you ultimately saw a blank string.
  - Even if you had used `'...'`, however, `$0` has *no* special meaning in the replacement operand; instead, you must **use `$&` to represent the matched string**, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375).

---

**To unconditionally separate ALL characters with spaces:**

[Drew's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54896795/45375) definitely works.
Here's a more PowerShell-idiomatic alternative:

```
PS> [char[]] '31222829' -join ' '
3 1 2 2 2 8 2 9
```

Casting a string to `[char[]]` returns its characters as an array, which `-join` then joins with a space as the separator.

Note: Since `-join` only places the specified separator (`' '`) *between* elements, the resulting string does *not* have a trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex with [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid the trailing space. Lookahead and lookbehind are zero-length assertions similar to `^` and `$` that match the start/end of a line. The regex `\d(?=.)` will match a digit when followed by another character.

```
PS> '123' -replace '\d(?=.)', '$0 '
1 2 3
```

To verify there's no trailing space:

```
PS> "[$('123' -replace '\d(?=.)', '$0 ')]"
[1 2 3]
```